# How do I check if I've met my maximum Roth IRA contribution on Vanguard?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, online-banking, vanguard

How do I check if I've reached the maximum yearly contribution amount for my Roth IRA Brokerage Account on Vanguard? I know that the limit for 2022 is $6,000, but I can't remember if I've contributed this year.

Comment: What's the point of asking the question if you already know the answer? It's not that it isn't immediately obvious on their website that you've spent hours figuring it out and wanted to share....

Comment: Not completely clear why so many downvotes. This question is technically [on-topic](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (although that doesn't automatically make it a good question). Is it "lack of research" or "not useful"? I could see that if the answer is really obvious for anyone using Vanguard, but I don't know if that's the case.

Comment: @littleadv I didn't know the answer when I posted the question. I only figured it out after posting.

Comment: @yoozer8 well... It's right there, on the screen, as the OP posted in their answer. You can't select a contribution without looking at how much you have left to contribute. These questions/answers are usually intended to boost one's rep, not really help anyone else.

Comment: @littleadv From the answer, it looks like you have to initiate a contribution/transfer in order to see how much you have contributed. That's not necessarily obvious/clear. To contrast, Fidelity shows a nice little chart right on your account summary screen when you first log in that shows your limit and contributions. Even shows current + prior year until April filing deadline (when both year contributions are allowed). If it were *that* obvious I'd be skeptical of this question, but by comparison Vanguard's approach is unintuitive.

Comment: @yoozer8 I used multiple custodians so far and find Vanguard the most intuitive actually. I don't find it necessary to be shown to me all the time, but when I do want to contribute - they tell me how much I still have left, and for which year. In any case, clearly the OP was able to figure it out in minutes between posting the question and the answer, so doubt it's a real issue a lot of Vanguard customers have.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Both the amount you've contributed and the yearly maximum are shown when contributing to a Roth IRA in Vanguard.

1. Login to [Vanguard](https://investor.vanguard.com/home).
2. Open your [Account Overview](https://personal1.vanguard.com/zaa-balances/).
3. Under Balances, click the Roth IRA account you want to check.
4. Click *Transfer Money > Contribute to IRA*

The amount you've contributed will be listed on the left under "*Where's the money going?*"

[image: Roth IRA contribution details for 2022]